# State not updating

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to update a widget when I got some data from my database. The widget that I'm trying to change is defined as a class variable:

```
Widget openFriendRequestNotificationWidget = new Container();
```

I'm using an empty container because I really don't need to render anything at the beginning and leaving it at null is no option.
I've got two functions, one to create my page and the other one the update my `openFriendRequestNotificationWidget`:

```
  Widget createFriendsPage() {
    if (currentUser.friends == null) {
      return new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          openFriendRequestNotificationWidget,
          new Material(
              child: new InkWell(
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text("Woops, looks like you have no friends yet.\nTap here to find some!", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ),
                onTap: () => createFriendsDialog(),
              )
          )
        ],
      );
    }
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        openFriendRequestNotificationWidget,
        new Text("ok")
      ],
    );
  }

  void createReceivedFriendRequestsNotification() {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("friend_requests").child(currentUser.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      Map<String, Map<String, String>> response = snap.value;
      if (response != null) {
        this.setState(() {
          print("Changing widget");
          openFriendRequestNotificationWidget = new Container(
            child: new Text("You've got ${response.length.toString()} new friend requests!"),
            color: Colors.black,
          );
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The variable is updating in `createReceivedFriendRequestsNotification` but it is not re-rendering.
Could someone help out?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9614

Comment: where do you call `createFriendsPage()`?

Comment: Thanks for this! I understand that because I use a column, which takes a list, the widget is not rebuilding because the list still contains the same variables even though I changed one (correct me if I'm wrong!). So how could I fix this? I will need a list for the column's widgets, no?

Comment: I call `createFriendsPage()` in `initState()`, so when my widget is first build.

Comment: Creating a complete new array every time looks like a waste. Especially when you are for example only trying to change some text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling `createFriendsPage` in `initState()`, then it means that the code inside `initState()` is called only once, which is to build the UI. 
If it's possible, I suggest that you call your `createFriendsPage` inside the override method `build()`

```
   class FriendPage extends StatefullWidget{
          //instantiate your state ..  }

   class FriendsPageState extends State<FriendPage> {
         @override 
         Widget build(Build context) {
               return cteateFriendsPage(); 
         }

         //other methods here ...
     }
```

Comment: I couldn't just return `createFriendsPage()` because of my app structure. But the idea of not calling the method in `initState()` got it to work!